# React Native: React Navigation - use the same header component in every screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

So, I'm trying to use React Navigation and I want to use the same Header component across all my screens.

I used the `expo-cli` to create the project.

In my `MainTabNavigator.js` file, I have a `HomeStack` and `SettingsStack`, and they look like this:

```
const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: "screen" },
  default: {}
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen
  },
  config
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <NavButton
      focused={focused}
      name={focused ? "star" : "create"}
      label={focused ? "Save" : "New"}
    />
  )
};

HomeStack.path = "";
```

At the bottom of the file, I have my `tabNavigator`

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
    SettingsStack
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveTintColor: "#fff",
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 14
      },
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderTopColor: "#fff",
        height: 70,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        paddingTop: 10
      }
    }
  }
);

tabNavigator.path = "";

export default tabNavigator;
```

I tried adding a `<Header />` component in the `navigatorOptions` and `defaultNavigationOption` above the `tabBarOptions` in the `createBottomTabNavigator` function.

Similar to this:

```
...
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: <Header />
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveTintColor: "#fff",
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 14
      },
 ...
```

but this just gives me a blank header... not using my component.

I currently have the functionality I want, but I have to go into each `Screen` file and add:

```
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  header: <Header />
};
```

Currently using `"react-navigation": "^3.11.0"`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I'm achieving this.
Create a CustomHeader component like this:

```
const MyHeader = (navigation) => {
return {
    header: props => <MyCustomHeader {...props} />,
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
    headerTintColor: '#000',
};
}
```

Then include it in `defaultNavigationOptions` in your stack navigator

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Launch: {
        screen: LaunchComponent,
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Launch",
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return MyHeader(navigation)
    }
}
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks Hamza, I used your answer to get something working. It's essentially the same thing, but, as I have multiple `createStackNavigator` calls, I just added your suggestion to a config object and added the config to each method call. I will post answer here as well that covers my unique specifics.

Comment: Could you add some explanation about why this works?

Comment: Hey Daltron, React official docs explained this very well. Go through it once, it will be a great investment of time.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#sharing-common-navigationoptions-across-screens

Comment: ``return`` keyword is what's missing for me

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to achieve similar solution for DrawerNavigator. The only way to do this was to create HOC component.

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

const NavHeader = props => {
 // ... NavHeader code goes here 
};

export const withHeader = Component => {
  return props => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <NavHeader {...props} />
        <Component {...props} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
};
```

Then in your Drawer you do:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
      component={withHeader(DashboardContainer)} // <--- Wrap it around component here.
    />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your StackNavigator as parent of your BottomTabNavigator, doing it will let you have a single header for all the bottomTabs.
If you use this approach, and need for some reason to have a `backButton` on your header you have to change it manually yourself.

```
const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(bottomRoutesConfig, bottomNavigatorConfigs)

createStackNavigator:({ tabNavigator : bottomTabNavigator },{ defaultNavigationOptions :{ header : <Header/> }})
```

Doing this you can use one global header for all the screens, but as said, to change something on the header based off the screen you have to change it yourself, making the header know in what location the user currently is.

Answer (score -1):

set `header` to `null` in every screen and load your component on each screens

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Header />
      </View>
     )
   }
}
```

so, the default `header` of `react-navigation` will be `null` and you can load your custom component as header

**OR**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    // headerTitle instead of title
    headerTitle: <Header />,
  };

  /* render function, etc */
}
```

use `headerTitle` instead of `title` to load your custom component

Comment: drawback of this method is that you dont have access to the navigation prop inside your header - this prevents you to do back action