# React Native custom header component navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation and trying to implement a custom header will be visible on every page. tried to follow the example in this link and it's all good. My header is displayed, but now i'm trying to navigate back to the home screen using the HOME link in the header navigation is not happening.

[React Native: React Navigation - use the same header component in every screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844711/react-native-react-navigation-use-the-same-header-component-in-every-screen)

When debugging my header component i can clearly see the navigation prop but not sure why it's not navigating. My code is below. any help appreciated.

Creating stack navigator

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 Home: {
  screen: MeetingList,    

 },
 MeetingDisplay: {
  screen: MeetingDisplay
 }
 },{
   initialRouteName: "Home",
   defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
       return MyHeader(navigation)
   }  
 });
```

Custom header component

```
const MyHeader = (navigation) => {
   return {
       header: props => <Header navigation= {navigation} />,
       headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#000' },
       headerTintColor: '#000',
   };
 }
```

My header component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, } from 'react-native';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       /  /this.params = props.navigation.state.params;
       this.state = {

       }        
     }

render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('MeetingList')}>HOME</Text>
            </View>
        </>
    )
   }
}

 export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('MeetingList')}
```

to

```
onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Home')}
```

what you are doing wrong is, you are passing screen name, you should pass the name of the route with which you are defining screen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you. That instantly fixed it!!! I'm struggling to understand many things about react native. Could you give some pointers as to why your change resolved my issue?

Comment: You had created a navigation const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 Home: {
  screen: MeetingList,    

 },
 MeetingDisplay: {
  screen: MeetingDisplay
 }  in this the routes are Home and MeetingDisplay , and screens are MeetingList and MeetingDisplay , what you are doing wrong is you are passing a screen name , you should always navigate by using route name only

Comment: ok thanks for the info. so evey time you call navigation.navigate you should only every pass a route name not a screen? so you have to setup multiple routes containing all the different screen names? I'm slightly confused but that.